# How to do Codebuild file_path filter on monorepo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, filter, webhooks, filepath

AWS codebuild fails to execute file_path filter in group filters on a monorepo hosted on Github and for every commit all projects in monorepo gets built.

We have a monorepo that looks like:

```
erp
  |_ dir1
  |_ dir2
  |_ functions
        |_ proj1
        |_ proj2
```

We have created a pipeline that uses Github webhook built via cloud formation.

The following code shows how we build the pipeline and codebuild (for the sake of this example build and deploy are in one AWS::CodeBuild::Project):

```
  Webhook:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Webhook
    Properties:
      AuthenticationConfiguration:
        SecretToken:
          Ref: GithubToken
      Filters:
      - JsonPath: "$.ref"
        MatchEquals: refs/heads/{Branch}
      Authentication: GITHUB_HMAC
      TargetPipeline:
        Ref: Pipeline
      TargetAction: SourceCodeRepo
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${Stage}${AppName}PipelineWebhook
      TargetPipelineVersion:
        Fn::GetAtt: Pipeline.Version
      RegisterWithThirdParty: 'true'

  BuildAndDeploy:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${Stage}-${AppName}"
      Artifacts:
        Type: NO_ARTIFACTS
      Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:2.0
        EnvironmentVariables:
        - Name: BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET
          Value:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${Stage}BuildArtifactsBucket"
        - Name: CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT
          Value:
            Ref: Stage
        - Name: CURRENT_BUILD
          Value:
            Ref: AppName
      Cache:
        Type: S3
        Location:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: "${Stage}BuildArtifactsBucket"
      ServiceRole:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: ${Stage}CodeBuildServiceRole
      Source:
        Type: GITHUB
        Location: "https://github.com/mountainequipmentcoop/erp-integration"
        BuildSpec:
          Fn::Sub: "${AppPath}/cicd/buildspec.yml"
      Triggers:
        Webhook: true
        FilterGroups:
        - - Type: EVENT
            Pattern: PUSH
          - Type: HEAD_REF
            Pattern: ^refs/heads/.*
          - Type: FILE_PATH
            Pattern:
              Fn::Sub: "${AppPath}/.*"
            ExcludeMatchedPattern: false

  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: "${Stage}BuildArtifactsBucket"
        Type: S3
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AppName}-${Stage}"
      RoleArn:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: ${Stage}CodePipelineExecutionRole
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      Stages:
      - Name: github-erp-integration
        Actions:

        - Name: SourceCodeRepo
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Source
            Owner: ThirdParty
            Version: 1
            Provider: GitHub
          OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: SourceCodeAsZip
          Configuration:
            Owner:
              Ref: GithubUser
            Repo:
              Ref: GithubRepo
            Branch:
              Ref: GithubBranch
            OAuthToken:
              Ref: GithubToken
            PollForSourceChanges: false
          RunOrder: 1

      - Name: build-and-deploy
        Actions:

        - Name: lambda-functions
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Build
            Owner: AWS
            Provider: CodeBuild
            Version: "1"
          Configuration:
            ProjectName:
              Ref: BuildAndDeploy
          InputArtifacts:
          - Name: SourceCodeAsZip
          OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: BuildArtifactAsZipAzureFileTransferLambdas
          RunOrder: 1
```

The following section is where we need to establish a trigger per project:

```
      Triggers:
        Webhook: true
        FilterGroups:
        - - Type: EVENT
            Pattern: PUSH
          - Type: HEAD_REF
            Pattern: ^refs/heads/.*
          - Type: FILE_PATH
            Pattern:
              Fn::Sub: "${AppPath}/.*"
            ExcludeMatchedPattern: false
```

And the values of the ${AppPath} could be:

- erp/functions/proj1
- erp/functions/proj2

which then gets translated to (for example for proj1):

```
          - Type: FILE_PATH
            Pattern:
              Fn::Sub: "erp/functions/proj1/.*"
```

I also tried the following variations as FILE_PATH pattern:

```
- erp/functions/proj1/.*
- erp/functions/proj1/*.*
- erp/functions\/proj1\/.*
- erp/functions\/proj1\/*.*
- ^erp/functions/proj1/.*
- ^erp/functions/proj1/*.*
- ^erp/functions\/proj1\/.*
- ^erp/functions\/proj1\/*.*
```

However these group filters on AWS codebuild project never functions on a PUSH. What happens is when I change something in proj1 both proj1 and proj2 gets built. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

> Update: I also tried it via web interface, it's not working. I built everything manually.

Comment: How did you end up setting this up?

Comment: I'm sorry not to know exactly how the pattern matching works, but you definitely don't need the trailing ".*". Verify that your webhooks are working. In the build details you have a link to the github webhook.